# Legend does not show in R plot function

Tags: r

I am new to R. I tries a lot of ways. But I can not make the legend show in the graph. The following is my code. Can anyone help?

```
plot(cycle_filt_ts[,1],main="Filtered Estimate of Transitory Component", ylim = c(-3,2),xlab="", type = "l", col=1)
lines(cycle_filt_ts[,2], type = "l", col=2)
legend(x="top",                          # Add legend to plot
   legend = c("a","b"),
   lty = 1, lwd = 1,
   col = 1:2)
```

[image: Graph without legend]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a picture of your outputted graph?

Comment: Can we have a [mcve] please? This graph doesn't look like it's generated by the standard base-R `plot()`/`lines()` ... I suspect these are `zoo` objects?

Comment: When I run that `legend` call on a plot made with base graphics I do get the expected result. So you need to provide the requested [MCVE]. I doubt that the objects are zoo-class. Plotting of zoo objects is pretty much the same as ordinary data. And msking a test case shows that your code makes a legend on one of them, too.